# Factories on Laravel 5.2 not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a very strange problem with Laravel 5.2 factories.

I have recently upgraded from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 following the upgrade guide on the Laravel website. All works as exepected except one factory. Yes the others work ok. Here are two of the factories:

```
$factory->define(App\Client::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name'              => $faker->company,
        'building'          => $faker->buildingNumber,
        'street'            => $faker->streetName,
        'town'              => $faker->city,
        'postcode'          => $faker->postcode,
        'country'           => 'UK',
        'telephone'         => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'fax'               => $faker->phoneNumber,
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Shift::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'client_id'         => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 15),
        'user_id'           => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 15),
        'start'             => $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate='now', $endDate='+60 days'),
        'public'            => $faker->boolean(),
    ];
});
```

The top factory works no problem but the second one doesn't run at all cause my db seed to throw an error because its not populating the client_id which is a foreign key.

The only difference between the two models is that the client model doesn't use timestamps where as the shift model does. Other than that they are identical.

I will keep plugging away but any help to shed light on this would be greatly received.

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem. It appears that if the model has even a blank constructor function the factory will not run. Has anybody else come up against this problem? My model will need a constructor for final deployment so I'll have to add it in later.

Comment: You should _not_ be overriding the constructor in Eloquent models. Also, it’d be easier for people to diagnose the issue if you actually posted the error message you receive. Error messages are there you tell what went wrong, not be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add your own constructor, are you making sure to call parent::__construct() inside it?

Comment: I wasn't doing this. Thank you solved my problem. Could I ask you what this passes to the constructor?

Comment: @Gavin Sorry I don't know the exact reason but it required. Let me know if you get the reason.